# Associating Specific SP List Items with Specific SP Library Documents/Images

Tags: splistitem, sharepoint-library

I need to create a SP list of certifications from an Excel spreadsheet.

I need to create a SP library to archive existing and new certification documents/images and upload existing document/image to library.

The certification documents are/can be pdf or image files - (should this library be a 'Document' or 'Image' library?).

Each Employee may appear on the certification list once or mulitple times based on the number of certifications they have.

Each Employee may have one or more certification documents in the library.

There are fifteen different certification titles available to choose from.

Each Member has a 'UniqueID'. The UniqueID is formatted as follows and appears allowing side each 'Item' (certification) on the SP list associate with the Member.

UniqueID = First Initial First Name / First Initial Last Name / Last Four of SSN

Member: Joe Schmoe

Last Four: 1234

UniqueID: JS1234

The Member's will need to ability to update, edit, or delete items from the SP list and associated item in the SP library.

At list and library creation (and for all addition of modifications to the SP list), how do I associate each line item on the SP list to its unique and specific document/image in the library?

Answer (score 1):

*Assuming you need the separate list and library without questioning if that can be changed*

What you are looking for is a "Relationship" in a Relational Data Model. "Relationship" requires a Foreign Key. Microsoft SharePoint's solution for Foreign Keys in general is Lookup fields. I would highly recommend using Lookup fields in any situation where there is a type of Relationship required, unless specific cases. There is no limit of 2000 items on lookup fields. You can Proof-of-Concept-Test that by creating two lists one looking up on the other, and creating 2000+ items with a script and see how that perfectly works.

Answer (score 0):

Mght not be the direct answer, but I would do what you want this way:

1. Create a single Document library.
2. Add the following fields to it:

- Member (People field)
- UniqueID (Text field)
- Certificate (Choice field). Define all types of certificates you have

3. Done.

Now simply start uploading your certificates to a single library. As simple as that.

If you want to add security to your library. Then do the following

- Navigate to the library settings > Advanced settings
- Set **Create items and edit items that were created by the user**

[image]

Then you can ask the members to upload the certificates. This will make they will be the creators of these documents and they will be able to update only their documents, but not their colleagues'.

Comment: Thank you for the comment.

I need to tie a specific document in said Library to a specific line item in a corresponding SP List.

How do I do that? 

Each line item in the List (because each is different even though multiple items may belong to the same Employee), should have a corresponding UniqueID to the item in the Library.

Comment: If you absolutely have to do it, what about creating a lookup column inside your document library? This lookup will point to your list. This way you'll have a connection.

Comment: Yes; thank you for your comment.

I have heard that Lookup columns for this purpose become problematic (performance-wise), after the source List becomes a certain size.

Is this not your understanding?

Comment: This is accurate. But if your list is no more than, let's say 200-300 items you'll be fine.

Comment: The SP List will be 2000+ items, and growing. :-)

Any suggestions about how I can manage this issue?

I need to be able to recall (view in a Power Apps Gallery), a specific item from the SP List and view the corresponding image/document from the SP Library.How do I tie each SP List Item to the SP Library Image/Document?

Comment: Well. in this case, I would just go with my approach that uses a single library. I might be missing something, but you might only need a single library, with no lists.Or, you can still keep a list. But only use it inside your Power App, for your gallery.

Comment: I need the List and the Library.

The List contains all of the corresponding data associated with the certificate (the who, what, where, and why).

The Library is an archive for the certificate document (whether PDF, Word, or image file).